# argmax() method from numpy is returning only first maximum, How to find indexes of all maximum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have below code

```
import numpy as np
np.argmax(np.array([5,5,4]))
```

This returns only 0. I was expecting that will return all indices where maximum occur i.e. 0 & 1

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to find all indexes of the max value of the array.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([5,5,4])
res = np.where(a == a.max())[0]
print(res)
# [0 1]
```